# Select-String pattern finds only partial string match of -cmatch

Tags: regex, powershell, text

I am trying to put together a string replacement routine. I have got as far as isolating the substring matches for two strings stored in array of strings `$lines`. Except there is a problem:

```
[string[]]$lines = "160 FROG Kermit  164 Big Bird_Road, Wellsville Singer","161 PIGGY Miss Pretty 1640 Really Long Main_Road, Whathellville Prima Donna"
# match string from last number to comma
foreach ($line in $lines) {
    if ($line -cmatch '\d\s\w[a-z]*\s.*,') {
        Write-Host "Found match!"
        $line | Select-String -Pattern '\d\s\w[a-z]*\s.' -AllMatches |
            ForEach-Object { 
                $x = $_.Matches[1].Value 
                Write-Host "x is:" $x
            }
    }
```

The first regex in `$line -cmatch '\d\s\w[a-z]*\s.*,'` is correct according to testing in Expresso. I want the address part of the string from last street number to comma. I am looking to replace the street basename spaces with underscores eg `Big Bird_Road` with `Big_Bird_Road` and `Really Long Main_Road` with `Really_Long_Main_Road`
The problem is that the second regex contained in: `$line | Select-String -Pattern '\d\s\w[a-z]*\s.' -AllMatches |`
Cannot be completed. As it is here. The output is:

```
Found match!
x is: 4 Big B
Found match!
x is: 0 Really L
```

The substring has not been captured yet! And if I add the remaining `*,` I get no output at all for `x is:`

Why doesn't the first regex (used with `-cmatch`) work in the same way when used as a `Select-String` pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a replace for that format in the strings, you can might use `-replace` and might use a patter to match the spaces only to replace them with an underscore:

```
(?<=\d\s+\w[a-zA-Z\s_]*)\s(?=[^\d,]*,)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind to assert what to the left is

  - `\d\s+\w[a-zA-Z\s_]*` Match a digit, 1+ whitespace chars, a word char and optionally repeat the listed characters in the character class
- `)` Close the lookbehind
- `\s` Match a whitespace char (or `\s+` to match 1 or more)
- `(?=[^\d,]*,)` Assert a comma to the right after matching optional chars other than a digit or comma

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8g1R9P/1)

```
[string[]]$lines = "160 FROG Kermit  164 Big Bird_Road, Wellsville Singer","161 PIGGY Miss Pretty 1640 Really Long Main_Road, Whathellville Prima Donna"

foreach ($line in $lines) {
    $line -replace "(?<=\d\s+\w[a-zA-Z\s_]*)\s(?=[^\d,]*,)","_"
}
```

Output

```
160 FROG Kermit  164 Big_Bird_Road, Wellsville Singer
161 PIGGY Miss Pretty 1640 Really_Long_Main_Road, Whathellville Prima Donna
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your solution. I was planning to use `-replace` but hadn't got that far. Your regex demo highlights only the target spaces! I was trying to get the whole target string highlighted. My thinking was around the wrong way.